# Arreglos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Como puedo hacer para que en mi programa no se pueda agregar el mismo nombre en el arreglo de nombre[x]. para que quede de la misma manera que el ID, es decir que si el mismo nombre es registrado mas de una vez me aparezca el mensaje de "NOMBRE YA REGISTRADO" y no me permita seguir el registro al menos que cambie el nombre.

```js
var opcion_menu;
var aux_idprof;
var id_prof=[];
var nombre=[];
var aux_nombre;
var x=0;
var y=0;
var z=0;
var renglon=0;
var activo=0;
var menu_profesores;
var ya_esta=0;

var ya_estanombre=0;



do{
  opcion_menu=prompt ("Ingrese la opcion deseada: \n 1.Profesores \n 2.Grupo/Materia \n 3.Alumnos \n 4.Reportes \n 5.Calificaciones \n 6.Salida");
  
  if(opcion_menu==1){
  
    do{
   menu_profesores=prompt("Ingrese la opcion deseada: \n1.Captura \n2.Consultas \n3.Cambios \n4.Cancelaciones \n5.Regreso");
    if(menu_profesores==1)//CAPTURAS PROFESORES
    {
     renglon=renglon+1; 
    do{
      ya_esta=0; 
   aux_idprof=prompt("Ingrese su ID"+"\n"+"Registro no.: "+renglon)
    for(x=0;x<=renglon;x++){
      if(aux_idprof==id_prof[x]){
        ya_esta=1;
        alert("ID ya Registrado")
      }
    }
  }while(ya_esta!==0);
  if(ya_esta!=1){ 
    id_prof[renglon]=aux_idprof; 
    
   do{
      ya_estanombre=0; 
   aux_nombre=prompt("Ingrese su nombre completo")
    for(x=0;x<=renglon;x++){
      if(aux_nombre==nombre[x]){
        ya_estanombre=1;
        alert("Nombre ya Registrado")
      }
    }
   
  }while(ya_estanombre!==0);

  
  }
 
  
  }//Registrar profesor
      
    }while(menu_profesores!=5);
  }//MENU PROFESORES
 
  if(opcion_menu==2){}//MENU MATERIA
  if(opcion_menu==3){}//MENU ALUMNOS
  if(opcion_menu==4){}//MENU REPORTES
  if(opcion_menu==5){}//MENU CALIFICACIONES
  
  
  
  }while(opcion_menu!=6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el metodo [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf) que retorna el indice del elemento si existe, de lo contrario retornara -1:

```js
var nombres = [];
while(true)
{
 var nombre = prompt("Ingrse el nombre \n escriba 0 para salir");
 
  if(nombre == "0")
  {
     break;
  }
  if(nombres.indexOf(nombre) == -1 && nombre != null)
  {
    nombres.push(nombre);
  }
  else
  {
    alert("El nombre ya fue registrado.");
  }
}

console.log("Nombres registrados");
for(var i = 0; i < nombres.length;i++)
{
  console.log(nombres[i]);
}
```

Solo tendras que adaptarlo a tu codigo y listo.